# What does "scrap it out " mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I could not find the meaning of "scrap out" in online dictionaries.

I found the above-mentioned phrase in the following sentence:

> In this golf game, you are dropped into the course with six other
>   players and are asked to scrap it out for victory.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a native American English speaker but non-golfer, I didn't understand this either.

Comment: @TypeIA - You were never in a "scrap" as a child??

Comment: @HotLicks I was in quite a few _scrapes_, but never a _scrap_. I'm familiar with the adjective _scrappy_ but never heard it used as a verb in this way. Maybe this is regional... I'm midwestern with a southern family. Or maybe I've been living under a rock (as my friends who golf would surely claim).

Comment: @TypeIA -- A "scrape" is a difficult situation, possibly but not necessarily a conflict per se, and possibly but not necessarily involving physical or figurative violence.  A "scrap" implies a conflict of some sort.

Comment: I can't find a reference, hence the comment, but the etymology is fighting for scraps (think puppies when you take out the leftovers from dinner).

Answer (score 14):

The sense is to “fight for” victory.

Close to the sense suggested by Green a Dictionary of Slang

***[Scrap:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/rqynjui)***

> to fight:
>
> 1935  [US]    N. Algren ‘Thundermug’ Texas Stories (1995) 72:
>
> - Sometimes I have to scrap some perty tough customers.

You can find other usage examples ***[here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scrap%20it%20out%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).***

Answer (score 7):

Scrap can also refer to a [fight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrap), and is often used to describe minor quarrels or sports competitions that get really heated. So saying they have to "scrap it out" means they have to fight competitively for victory, essentially.

Answer (score 3):

"Scrap" is slang for "fight". If someone is "scrappy", it means they can and are willing to fight. It has connotations of self-reliance, resourcefulness, and resilience.

It sounds like it's being used figuratively here - that the six players play until one of them is victorious, with no other elimination prior to one of them winning. The self-reliant/resourceful/resilient connotation indicates that the competition will require a player to be all of those things in order to win.

Answer (score 2):

To be complete, we would also have to explain the *out* adverb, and the *for* preposition, in the phrasal verb **to scrap it out for (something)**.

*Out* means

> c. To a finish or conclusion: *Play the game out*
>   [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=out)

And *for* indicates the aim, of course.

So the sentence:

> In this golf game, you are dropped into the course with six other
>   players and are asked to **scrap it out for** victory.

means that they would have to fight to the end, so that one of them could achieve victory.

Answer (score 0):

`Scrap` here is slang for `brawl`, often with a diminutive meaning, although it can be used metaphorically and therefore does not necessarily mean just a physical altercation that comes to literal blows. There are very few contexts where you can't just replace `scrap` with `brawl` to convey the same idea, both as a noun and as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in this context "fight it out" would be another way to express the meaning, but using the phrase "scrap it out" tinges the competition with a feeling of it being of less consequence than other, perhaps simultaneous or contemporaneous, similar competitions.